# How do I add a custom term to a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "service". I have a form on the front end that users can create a service with. There are also 5 taxonomies that a service can use. When the user creates a service, I want them to be able to add tags to their service regardless of which taxonomy they choose for their service. My script currently starts off by creating the post, then it checks if each of the tags exists, if a tag doesn't exist, it is inserted, if it does exist, the id of the existing tag is used. I keep getting the WP error 'Invalid Taxonomy'.

Is there a way to add a term to a custom post type regardless of it's taxonomy?

Here is the code that registers the CPT and taxonomies:

```
function init(){
    register_post_type('service', 
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => 'Services',
                        'singlular_name' => 'Service',
                        'add_new' => 'Add New',
                        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Service',
                        'edit_item' => 'Edit Service',
                        'new_item' => 'New Service',
                        'view_item' => 'View Service',
                        'view_items' => 'View Services',
                        'search_items' => 'Search Services',
                        'not_found' => 'No services found',
                        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No services found in trash',
                        'all_items' => 'All Services',
                        'archives' => 'Archived Services',
                        'featured_image' => 'Service Logo',
                        'use_featured_image' => 'Use as logo',
                        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove logo',
                        'set_featured_image' => 'Set logo',
                        'menu_name' => 'Services'
                ),
                'description' => 'Services for events provided by people.',
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-id-alt',
                'capability_type' => 'services',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'supports' => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions'),
                'has_archive' => true           
            )
        );

    $band_labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Bands', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Band', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Bands' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Bands' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Band' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Band:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Band' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Band' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Band' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Band Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Bands' ),
        );

        // Now register the taxonomy

        register_taxonomy('Band',array('service'), array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $band_labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bands' ),
        ));
}
add_action('init', 'init);
```

Here is where i modify a service:

```
function modify(){
        $post = get_post($this->id);
        if($post != null){
            $post_id = wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $this->id,
                'post_title' => $_POST['business_name']
            ));
            if($_POST['location'] != $this->info['meta']['service_location'][0]){
                update_post_meta($this->id, 'service_location', $_POST['location']);
                $this->geocode($_POST['location']);
                update_post_meta($this->id, 'service_lat', $this->geocode['lat']);
                update_post_meta($this->id, 'service_lon', $this->geocode['lon']);
            }
            $meta = array('description', 'max_distance', 'category', 'website', 'email');
            foreach($meta as $key){
                if($_POST[$key] != $this->info['meta']['service_'.$key][0] || !isset($this->info['meta']['service_'.$key][0])){
                    if(get_post_meta($this->id, 'service_'.$key, true)){
                        update_post_meta($this->id, 'service_'.$key, $_POST[$key]);
                    } else {
                        add_post_meta($this->id, 'service_'.$key, $_POST[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            $tags = explode(',', $_POST['tags']);
            $keywords = array();
            if(count($tags) > 0){
                foreach($tags as $tag){
                    $term_exists = term_exists($tag);
                    if($term_exists !== 0 && $term_exists !== null){
                        $term = $term_exists;
                    } else {
                        $new_term = wp_insert_term($tag, 'service');
                        if(!is_wp_error($new_term)){
                            $term = $new_term['term_id'];
                        } else {
                            die($new_term->get_error_message());
                        }
                    }
                    $keywords[] = $term;
                }
            }
            $keywords = array_map('intval', $keywords);
            $keywords = array_unique($keywords);
            $add_terms = wp_set_object_terms($this->id, $keywords, 'service');
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When registering a taxonomy you need to specify post types. Does this  work with your implementable?

Comment: Doesn't the second parameter of register_taxonomy() assign the tax to the post type? And also, in my dashboard, I see Services in the menu and it's dropdown has all the taxonomies I register for Service cpt.